# Still can't play the video on my android phone using video view

Tags: android, video

I am trying to write a very very very basic videoview to play the video in my phone
I searched a lot of posts and try to copy their code but it all fails.
It always says can't play this video.
There are just a few lines of code but it still won't work, kind of frustrated.
I found the code on youtube

The video is in .3gp format
I tried to export the apk package to my phone (signed)
I created a raw folder under res to store the testVideo that is going to be played.
I tried to comment and comment this two lines, both are not working.
//videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this))
//videoView.requestFocus()

```
package com.example.mymediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoviewer);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        String urlpath = "android:resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test;

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        // videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        // videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for playing a video.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(VIDEO_URI);
videoView.start();
```

make sure that your video format is supported and that the path to the video is correct.  You can test that your video play is working by streaming a video instead of using a stored file.

Try playing this demo video by adding internet permissions to your application and using this URI as the VIDEO_URI :  "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4"

Comment: pwilmot Thank for your big help !!!
Now I can play the demo video you gave me on emulator.
It's already a huge step for me!

But I still can't play that demo video on my phone.
Do you know the reason why?

I use export signed package and then get the two file:
1. myvideo 
2. myMediaPlayer.apk

I copy and paste the two files in my phone's sd card location 

I already checked the USB debugging in my phone.

But my phone still can't play the video.
Do you have any clue ?
Or may be there are some setting in my phone I need to change or
I forgot to do ?

Comment: And I just noticed that my Android version is 2.3.6 but it seems
that I can't update it cause when I search for software update
it says no update available.

Will it be the problem of my android version ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or other debug information in the logs?  also that version of android is from September 2, 2011 so you might want to look into upgrading